# Config SVNKit like a built-in option on NetBeans 17

Tags: svn, netbeans, built-in, svnkit

As I know, starting from NetBeans 9.0 and subsequent versions, SVNKit is no longer included as a built-in option for the Subversion integration.

If I want to use SVNKit specifically, I would need to download and install SVNKit separately and configure it as the Subversion client in NetBeans.

I know it would be tricky but are there anyways I config NetBeans17 so that SVNKit appears like a built-in option (like NetBeans8.2) without downloading anything ?

Thanks in advance!!